# Ocultar caixa de clique (toque) em um site HTML5/CSS3?

Tags: html5, css3

Estou fazendo um site para servir com um app para um trabalho na faculdade, o desing tá ok (por enquanto, e funcionou legal no smartphone.

Porém, no menu há um erro quando eu pressiono algum item do menu, uma caixa azul clara aparece, atrapalhando o desing do app, outra coisa é o hover dos < li > que estão aparecendo apenas quando mantenho o dedo pressionado por bastante tempo no item. Segue a imagem do erro:
[image: a misteriosa caixa azul atrapalha até o efeito do hover, a cor dele..]

A misteriosa caixa azul atrapalha até o efeito do hover, a cor dele..

Se não for possível remove-lo, como mudo a cor da caixa? Outro erro é a demora para carregar a página (aparece uma tela branca entre esse processo), exemplo a referências, estranho, pois só as fontes estão online.

Aqui então os arquivos css e html (de um modelo) sem imagens, claro:

```js
$(document).ready(main);

var contador = 1;

function main () {
 $('.menu_bar').click(function(){
  if (contador == 1) {
   $('nav').animate({
    left: '0'
   });
   contador = 0;
  } else {
   contador = 1;
   $('nav').animate({
    left: '-100%'
   });
  }
 });

 // Mostramos y ocultamos submenus
 $('.submenu').click(function(){
  $(this).children('.children').slideToggle();
 });
};
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:200);

* {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #F9FFF9   ;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web',sans-serif;
    text-align: justify;
}


.menu_bar {
 display:none;
    margin: 0;
}

header {
 width: 100%;
}

header#titulo h1{
    font-size: 19px;
    /*margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;*/
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background: #d40000;
}

header#titulo h2{
    font-size: 13pt;
    color: white;
    background: #80c939;

    text-align: center;
}

header nav {
 background:#80c939;
 z-index:100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 width:100%;
 margin: 0;
    
}

header nav ul {
 list-style:none;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

header nav ul li {
 display:inline-block;
 position: relative;
}

header nav ul li:hover {
 background:#d40000;
}

header nav ul li a {
 color: #444444;
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding: 20px;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
 color: white;;
}

header nav ul li a span {
 margin-right:10px;
}

nav img#logo{
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    top: 0;
}
nav img#logo:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}


footer#final{
    clear: both;
    border-color: #80c939;
    border-style: solid;
}



footer#final p{
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
}

.topo{
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    float: right;
    margin: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0px;
}
.topo:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
 body {
  padding-top:60px;
 }

 .menu_bar {
  display:block;
        margin: 0;
  width:100%;
        height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  background:#80c939;

 }

 .menu_bar .bt-menu {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
        margin: -1px;
  color: #444444;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-decoration: none ;
 }

 .menu_bar span {
        margin-top: -13px;
        padding: -10px;
  float:right;
  font-size: 40px;

 }
    
    .menu_bar a{
        text-align: center;
    }

 header nav {
  width: 80%;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  position: fixed;
  right:100%;
  margin-top: -7px;
  overflow: scroll;
        
 }
    
    header nav::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
    }

 header nav ul li {
        height: 50px;
 display: block;
 /*border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.4);*/
        text-align: left;
        border: 0px;

 }
    
    header nav ul li span{
        border: 0px;
        margin-top: -8px;
        float: right;

    }
    header nav ul li span img{
        border-width: 0;
        border: 0px;
    
        
    }
    
    
 header nav ul li a {
        margin-top: 0px;
        font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
 }
    nav img#logo{
        opacity: 1;
        position: auto;
        float: right;
        
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Menu</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilo.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js" ></script>
 <script src="../scripts/menu.js"></script>
 <script src="../scripts/voltar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="interface">
 <header>
  <div class="menu_bar">
            <a class="bt-menu"><span><img src="../icones/menu.png"/></span><img src="../icones/logo.png"/></a>
  </div>

  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="../index.html"><span><img src="../icones/inicio.png"/> </span>INICIAL</a></li>
    <li><a href="../paginas/artigos.html"><span> <img src="../icones/artigos.png"/> </span>ARTIGOS</a></li>
    <li><a href="../paginas/multimidia.html"><span><img src="../icones/multi.png"/>  </span>MULTIMÍDIA</a></li>
    <li><a href="../paginas/referencias.html"><span><img src="../icones/referencias.png"/>  </span>REFERÊNCIAS</a></li>
        <li><a href="../paginas/sobre.html"><span><img src="../icones/sobre.png"/>  </span>SOBRE</a></li>
   </ul>
<img id="logo" src="../imagens/banner.png"/>
  </nav>
 </header>
 <section id="corpo">
    <header id="titulo">
        <h1>Página Inicial</h1>
        <h2>Teste </h2>
    </header>
    
     
 </section>
    </div>
    
    <footer id="final">
       <span class="topo"><img src="../icones/voltar.png"/> </span>
        <p><b>&copy; 2015 - IFTM</b> <br>
        Leonardo, Guilherme, Carlos V., Matheus, Victor A. e Jóse Humberto. <br>
        <b>Desing por Leonardo Vilarinho.</b></p>
    </footer>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sobre a demora no carregamento, não sei o que pode ser, sobre essa caixa, se a cor está definida no css, mude o background para `transparent` ou `display: none;` ou até mesmo `opacity: 0;`

Comment: eu consegui diminuir isso com o :target

Comment: e conseguiu descobrir onde estava essa caixa?

Comment: Na verdade a tal 'caixa' misteriosa deveria  ser do próprio sistema do Windows Phone, e recentemente descobri que quando não manipulada pelo app ela segue a cor do tema do usuário, mas o target caiu muito bem